# Trying to stop instant validation with jQuery validate

Tags: jquery, validation, blur, onkeydown

I'm trying to prevent the jQuery validate plugin from checking input boxes as they are being typed into. Instead, I wish for the validation to occur when the input box in question has lost focus (e.g. the next input box has been selected...).

Here is what I have attempted so far.

```
    <script type = "text/javascript">
        $("#contact").validate({
            onkeyup: false,
            rules: {
                name: "required name",
                email: "required email",
                message: "required message"
            }
        });
    </script>
```

It's not yielding the expected result unfortunately. It's submitting the form and skipping the validation completely in fact.

Looking forward to your comments.

Comment: It's `onkeyup` not `onkeydown`.

Comment: Ha, sorry late night typo there. Checked and still no effect.

Comment: are those valid rule names?  perhaps you wnt to have "required" only.

Comment: Well I've switched to just 'required' and it's still skipping validation and submitting the form so I'm not sure that has made a telling difference unfortunately...

Comment: FIXED! I placed the 'onkeyup: false' within a separate validation script in the header and it did the trick. I think those rules were conflicting with another script I had in there too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's possible it comes down to timing.  try putting the call to validate() in ready() like so (from http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation#Example):

$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#commentForm").validate();
      });

Comment: Thanks, although I've fixed the issue this is going to be quite useful for me to be honest. I read elsewhere about a timing script that is reset after each keystroke as an alternative to onkeydown and/or onfocusout.

Answer (score 0):

The javascript onblur event might do what you need.

```
$('#contact').blur(function(){
    validator.validate()
});
```

As a side note, no javascript will run if you have errors in your code so make sure you are watching your error console. If your form is submitting without the validation that could be a possible cause. Can you post your form?